# Chart js scatter graph labels

Tags: chart.js, scatter-plot, scatter

I have a scatter graph using Chart.js and in the X axes I have time values (I use Moment.js).
The problem is that I want the scale reversed (see the image) but it doesn't work with the

```
scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            ...
            ticks: {
                reverse: true
             },
```

So I need to use the linear type.
The problem is that with the linear time in the X axes I see the seconds and what I want are the seconds in 'mm:ss' format, so I think I need to use labels.

The question is: how can I use the labels for the x axes in the scatter plot graph?
[graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFt0D.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is surprising that it doesn't work since the reverse option is a base config item (not specific to any certain scale). When I'm back at a computer I will investigate if this is a bug.

In the meantime, you can use the tick [`callback`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-creating-custom-tick-formats) option to format your labels.  Here is an example.

```
scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                // Create mm:ss labels
                callback: function(value, index, values) {
                    return moment.duration(value, 'seconds').format('mm:ss'); 
                }
            }
        }]
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If you want to check my code is here: https://codepen.io/fntgnn/pen/KWmgzW

Comment: I think I found the solution with the callback that you suggested because I have the seconds: https://codepaste.net/81444z